# Why does log not get generated when the SQL maintenance plan job fails to execute (agent job history shows job failed)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

In maintenance plan, under the reporting and logging setting I have configured a text file report to be generated and email report. This gets generated and I receive an email every time the maintenance plan job executes.

However, when the job fails to execute I can see that the job history shows that "The job failed" (for example when the user doesn't have permission to run the job), but the log file is not generated and email is not received. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: But the job history says "The job failed" - Is there any way to notify the operator about this?

Comment: Doesn't your 1st comment answer this? For example - since the job doesn't start there wont be any notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on to what Tibor said:

You mentioned "*...for example when the user doesn't have permission to run the job*". This is a failure that occurs at the **Job** before the Maintenance Plan is even attempted to be ran, and therefore the error is generated by the Job (and resultantly logged by the Job), not the Maintenance Plan, since the Job didn't even get that far.

A Job and a Maintenance Plan are two different objects in SQL Server which you happen to be using together, but theoretically a Job could contain any steps to run any type of SQL or command (doesn't even need to be a Maintenance Plan in the Job steps) and if the executing user doesn't have permissions to execute the Job, then the Job fails before any of it's steps are even ran.

As discussed in the comments, if you wanted to be notified on Job specific failures (such as the one in your example), you'd have to enable Notifications on the specific Job itself.

Comment: Does this event trigger the success or failure constraint of the maintenance plan task? I understand from your answer that maintenance plan execution doesn't even begin. So the answer is: NO. Correct? So the only place for me to notify an operator about this is via the job notification failure feature.

Comment: @variable Correct, you'd have to enable Notifications on the Job itself, since this was a failure of the Job itself.

Answer (score 1):

A maintenence plan is in the end an SSIS package. The package is what creates the report file. If the package fails to start, then there is nothing that can create the report file. I.e., the reason is due to the way that maint plans are implemented.

This is one of many reasons why many of us prefer alternative solutions, like for instance Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution. https://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Will either of the below help me to send the email for failure notification: 1. set up notify operator task upon task failure in maintenance plan; 2. configure failure notification on the job.

Comment: This thread is about the report file generated by a maint plan. Pls keep the email questions in your other thread about emailing from a maint plan.